# Android Google maps overlay balloon/annotation like iPhones

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps, popup

I've got overlay icons all over my map activity that each need to pop up a dialog when tapped.

Currently I just display Androids default AlertDialog.

I was hoping to instead be able to display a small balloon like iPhones 'annotation', see picture below.

Is there a simple way of achieving this in Android? Preferably without using some kind of external library?

[image]

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having gone down the "no library" route, you will probably want to use something like [Mapview Balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) by Jeff Gilfelt. You can incorporate the source OR use as a library.